# Is there a way to resize an image when live?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web

E.g. with something akin to firebug, so that you can see how other page elements wrap around it. I don't know of anything like this other than http://makiapp.com/maki , which is useful but not ideal as it doesn't wrap text around the image for example.

Is there a way to re-size images directly on a website?

Comment: can you clearify your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear on what exactly you want, but I made a fiddle none the less: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/r8J9F/2/

If you want to use this on your own pages, then you can just add the code as is, and add the class `resizable` to any elements (doesn't need to be images) that you want to be able to resize.

If you want to use it on a page without modifying its source, then you can open Firebug and run the code in the console, just swap out the `$('.resizable')` selection with something that will match the elements you want to resize. `$('*')` would apply it to everything.

The code:

```
var startX,startY,
    startW,startH,
    $box=null;
$('.resizable').mousedown(function(e){
    startX = e.pageX;
    startY = e.pageY;
    $box = $(this);
    startW = $box.innerWidth();
    startH = $box.innerHeight();
    return false;
});

$('body')
    .mouseup(function(){
        $box = null;
        return false;
    })
    .mousemove(function(e){
        if($box!=null){
            $box.innerWidth (startW + e.pageX-startX);
            $box.innerHeight(startH + e.pageY-startY);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ooh this is almost exactly what I want. Would it be possible to use this via firebug with a specific image on a web page?

Comment: You need a way to reference the image, for instance by id. `<img id="myimage">` could be selected by changing `$('.resizable')` to `$('#myimage')`. But there shouldn't be any harm in applying it to all images by using `$('img')`. Note though that if the image is wrapped inside a container with its own specific size, then resizing the image might not have any effect on the rest of the document flow. In that case you need to apply the resize to the wrapping element.